# Rate of change Pandas Data Frame after grouping

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python pandas and have been trying to get the rate of return using pct_change().  I would like to get monthly rate of change by feedcode.
This my current code:

```
In [134]:
df3 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sector_set.csv')
df3.set_index('Date', inplace= True)
df3= pd.DataFrame(df3,columns = ['Feed','Close']) # filter specific col​
grouped = df3.groupby('Feed')  #group by Feedcode
df3 = grouped.resample('BM', how=lambda x:x[-1]) #ending of every month only
df3['Rate_Return'] = df3.pct_change()  # Rate of Return of each feedcode
df3

OUTPUT:
                   Close  Rate_Return
Feed   Date
   A   2015-09-30  5.60     NaN 
       2015-10-30  5.75    0.026786  
  AAV  2015-09-30  4.32   -0.248696
       2015-10-30  4.62    0.069444
```

I have two issues:

1. The calculated rate of return is incorrect as it reference prior day feedcode price to calculate the return for the next feed code. For example, Feed AAV 2015-09-30 should be NaN and not -0.248696
2. I would like to remove all NaN

I am trying to calculate the returns to get something like this:

```
Output:
                   Close  Rate_Return
Feed   Date
   A   2015-10-30  5.75    0.026786  
  AAV  2015-10-30  4.32    0.069444
```

What is the best way of doing this?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Would be nice having a sample of your original dataset to work with, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you need groupby by `Feed` from multiindex and apply [`pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.pct_change.html). Then you can use subset of `df3`, where column `Rate_Return` is `notnull`

```
df3['Rate_Return'] = df3.groupby(level=0).pct_change() 
print df3
                 Close  Rate_Return
Feed Date                          
A    2015-09-30   5.60          NaN
     2015-10-30   5.75     0.026786
AAV  2015-09-30   4.32          NaN
     2015-10-30   4.62     0.069444

print df3[df3.Rate_Return.notnull()]
                 Close  Rate_Return
Feed Date                          
A    2015-10-30   5.75     0.026786
AAV  2015-10-30   4.62     0.069444
```

Comment: @jezrael pct_change() works on current/previous, how would you use it for previous/current in the same frame?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you can change order of columns by `df = df[::-1]`, apply `pct_change` and last return to original `print df.sort_index()`